# SoftwareSerial returns garbage when powered externally

Tags: arduino-nano, softwareserial, esp8266

I'm currently working on a project with the ESP8266 and Arduino Nano, and when I power the device via USB they talk to each other via SoftwareSerial just fine. I use the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor to monitor this communication. But when I power it with a 15 V wall wart to Vin it returns mostly garbage, again I can tell this with the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor (I know I shouldn't connect two power supplies at a time). When powered over 5 V USB everything is great. Why would I have a problem only when connected to an external power supply?

Comment: Have you measured this wall wart? 15V is high for Vin, and it might be noisy conceivably. Try a different one. Preferably lower voltage.

Comment: I did measure it. 15v is whats coming out. How would i check noise?

Comment: Put the meter on AC voltage and see if you get any reading. Try a different wall-wart. Recommended input voltage is 7 to 12 V.

Comment: @NickGammon i dont have another voltage supply. Can i use a voltage divider?

Comment: Voltage dividers are not recommended as voltage regulators. Are you using a level shifter for communicating with the ESP8266? Plus, can you measure what voltage is on the 5V pin when you are powering the Nano from the wall-wart?

Comment: @NickGammon im using a voltage divider for comm to esp. Yes i will measure it. What am i looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29863/discussion-between-nick-gammon-and-cjueden).

Comment: "Voltage dividers are not recommended as voltage regulators" - correct that to "Voltage dividers *cannot be used as* voltage regulators". It's not a question of recommendation, it's simple Ohm's Law that they cannot work.

Comment: Just to add my two pence quickly. Is it just that you need to have a common Ground? Try connecting the grounds of both devices together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the specifications they stat 12VDC is the max.  Your on board regulator is probably very hot and either shutting down or allowing the voltage to sag.  You can get a 9V wall Wart for under $5.  the 9V will keep the on-board regulator much cooler and add reliability.